# recoger dato de firebase por medio de equals

Tags: android, firebase

Estoy teniendo problemas para recoger unos datos que aparentemente no tenia complicación, la cuestion es quiero recoger los Si y los No de los objetos que obtengo y no soy capaz

dejo el codigo

```
  database.getReference("Events").child( code ).child( "Users" ).addValueEventListener( new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            int cont = 0; int si=0; int no=0; int mb=0;
          //  String Si="Si",No="No";
            String hola;
            for (DataSnapshot snapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

                User user = snapshot.getValue(User.class);
                data.add( user);
                hola = data.get( 0 ).getvote();

                if(hola.equals( "Si" )){
                    si++;
                }

                if (hola.equals( "No" )){
                    no++;
                }

                if(hola.equals( null )){
                    mb++;
                }
                cont++;
            }
            participantes = data.size();// Total participantes
            String participantesCast= Integer.toString( participantes );
            tvTotalParticipantes.setText( participantesCast );
            Log.i("Si","Si"+si);
            Log.i("No","No"+no);
            Log.i("mb","mb"+mb);
           /// Log.i("mb","mb"+hola);

        }
```

en el debug se me va todo al Si y al Mb y no entiendo que hago mal por que lo he intentado de varias maneras sin dar con la buena

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

añado clase User
    public class User {

```
private String name;
private String email;
private String avatar;
private List<String> events;
private String vote;
```

Comment: podrias poner la estructura de tu base de datos y la clase User.class?

Comment: @GastónSaillén puesto la clase User

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estas obteniendo siempre el mismo valor al hacer `.get(0)` en la lista `data`. No es necesario obtener el valor de la lista cuando tienes directamente la referencia del objeto en `user`. Intenta hacer:

```
String hola = user.getVote();

if(hola == null)
   mb++;
else if(hola.toLowerCase().Equals("si"))
   si++;
else if(hola.toLowerCase().Equals("no"))
   no++;
```

Comment: con el switch me sale otro fallo:
 Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.String.hashCode()' on a null object reference
pero gracias por el aporte

Comment: @lujan prueba con los condicionales if y else, pero ese era el problema, obtener el indice 0 de la lista, te actualice la respuesta.

Comment: Ahora si, pensaba que tenia que usar el data y de ahí recoger los datos uno a uno, gracias por la ayuda